# Python request won't authenticate

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

For some reason my script won't authenticate with the website, and scrape the content behind the login page

```
import requests
from lxml import html


USERNAME = "bla@gmail.com"
PASSWORD = "somePass999"

LOGIN_URL = "https://login.com/incidents"
URL = "https://login.com/secretstuff"


def main():
    session_requests = requests.session()

    # Get login csrf token
    result = session_requests.get(LOGIN_URL)
    tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
    authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='csrf']/@value")))[0]

    # Create payload
    payload = {
        "username": USERNAME, 
        "password": PASSWORD, 
        "csrf": authenticity_token
    }

    # Perform login
    result = session_requests.post(LOGIN_URL, data = payload, headers = dict(referer = LOGIN_URL))

    # Scrape url
    result = session_requests.get(URL, headers = dict(referer = URL))
    tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
    dump = tree.xpath("//div[@class='description-wrapper']")

    print(dump)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And:

```
<p class="password-item"><input class="xl email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="" autocomplete="off"></p>
<p class="password-item"><input class="xl password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Log in to your account" class="btn btn-large xl submitxl"></p>
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="c713053973d0491baf246ac52b30bdbd">
<input type="hidden" id="localeLang_input" value="en">
<input type="hidden" id="browser_locale_input" value="en_US">
```

For some reason it will only print the login page portal. I am not sure what else am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

- The target site may not authenticating you for some reason

  - Maybe because the POST data doesn't match the site's format
  - Or because the site (I think) uses Flask or Django in the backend
- You could be loading the final block too soon perhaps, try adding some delay before you start scraping. Maybe that could make a difference